# Update Authorization (Ruby on Rails Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

Mike Hart's tutorial on adding authorization presented the below code ([link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code-correct_user_before_filter) to original code listing) . Why does the method `update` make a call to `sign_in @user`. This seems redundant to me as the `before_filter :correct_user` should guarantee that the client is signed in because of `current_user?(@user)` in method `correct_user`.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  .
  .
  .
  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
  private

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the user is forced to update their password when updating attributes, this would render their current login invalid.

Comment: Ah you're right. I'd forgotten the remember_token changes after the user model is saved.